# Change wording used in sectioning such as \part

Tags: sectioning, naming, parts

I am busy writing an article that is not in English. It is divided into various parts so it makes sense for me to use the `\part{}` command. However, using `\part{}` adds the word "Part XX" to the document, which is not an Afrikaans word.

How can I redefine this command so that it adds "Deel I", "Deel II" etc?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example, we especially need to know your documentclass and how you set your document language.

Comment: I apologise, I decided that writing my final year-end projects would be an excellent excuse to learn Latex, so I am still very new do this. I inferred my documentclass as being `article`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\partname` to whatever you want, but probably what you want is

```
\usepackage[afrikaans]{babel}
```

which will redefine all the fixed strings to Afrikaans words, and to set up hyphenation for the language.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the babel package and it sorts out all my problems. It works fairly well. Now only to find a proper Afrikaans dictionary...